# Python app capturing with scaling monitor

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen, pywin32, win32gui

I'm trying to capture a window (in the example code I'll use firefox), I'm running 2 monitors the first one in 2736x1824 with 200% scaling and the second one in 1920x1080 with 100% scaling.

```
    from win32 import win32gui

    def enum_cb(hwnd, results):
       # CallBack function for enumeration
       winlist.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
    def get_screens():
        win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_cb, winlist)
        return [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if title]
    def get_screensbyname(screen_name):
       # Function who gets a screen by name
       winlist = get_screens()
       screens = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if screen_name in title.lower()]
       while len(screens) <= 0:
           winlist = get_screens()
           screens = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if screen_name in title.lower()]
       return screens
    winlist = []
    windows = get_screensbyname('firefox')
    window = windows[0][0]
    wRect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(window)
    cRect = win32gui.GetClientRect(window)
    print('GetWindowRect ', wRect)
    print('GetCLientRect ', cRect)
```

If the window is on the first screen it outputs

```
GetWindowRect (-7, -7, 1374, 878)
GetCLientRect (0, 0, 1368, 878)
```

If the window is on the second screen it outputs

```
GetWindowRect (2728, 345, 4664, 1401)
GetCLientRect (0, 0, 1920, 1048)
```

Now, to my understanding, it ignores the given scaling on the monitor. Since if I manually apply the scaling (using a calculator) the first output changes to

```
GetWindowRect (-14, -14, 2748, 1756)
GetCLientRect (0, 0, 2736, 1756)
```

How can I apply the scaling or the dpi awerness that is set on the monitor the window is on?

I need it to capture the inside area and stream it to a file or on the other screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is relatively simple add the following lines

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
```

It also works setting SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) don't know the difference between these two.
If anyone could explain it it would be nice.

NOTE: this answer will be set as solution tomorrow